# Azure Table Storage design question: Is it a good idea to use 1 table to store multiple types?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm just wondering if anyone who has experience on Azure Table Storage could comment on if it is a good idea to use 1 table to store multiple types?

The reason I want to do this is so I can do transactions.  However, I also want to get a sense in terms of development, would this approach be easy or messy to handle?  So far, I'm using Azure Storage Explorer to assist development and viewing multiple types in one table has been messy.

To give an example, say I'm designing a community site of blogs, if I store all blog posts, categories, comments in one table, what problems would I encounter? On ther other hand, if I don't then how do I ensure some consistency on category and post for example (assume 1 post can have one 1 category)?

Or are there any other different approaches people take to get around this problem using table storage?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to have perfect consistency, then using a single table is a good way to go about it. However, I think that you are probably going to be making things more difficult for yourself and get very little reward. The reason I say this is that table storage is extremely reliable. Transactions are great and all if you are dealing with very very important data, but in most cases, such as a blog, I think you would be better off just 1) either allowing for some very small percentage of inconsistent data and 2) handling failures in a more manual way.

The biggest issue you will have with storing multiple types in the same table is serialization. Most of the current table storage SDKs and utilities were designed to handle a single type. That being said, you can certainly handle multiple schemas either manually (i.e. deserializing your object to a master object that contains all possible properties) or interacting directly with the REST services (i.e. not going through the Azure SDK). If you used the REST services directly, you would have to handle serialization yourself and thus you could more efficiently handle the multiple types, but the trade off is that you are doing everything manually that is normally handled by the Azure SDK.

There really is no right or wrong way to do this. Both situations will work, it is just a matter of what is most practical. I personally tend to put a single schema per table unless there is a very good reason to do otherwise. I think you will find table storage to be reliable enough without the use of transactions.

You may want to check out the [Windows Azure Toolkit](http://azuretoolkit.codeplex.com). We have designed that toolkit to simplify some of the more common azure tasks.

Comment: Thank you so much Nathan for your insight! It's great to know Table Storage is so reliable. Based on this fact, I'll design my app accordingly. I was looking at the Azure Table Storage whitepaper, in section 7.2 it explained a technique for Cross-Table Consistency, it is very complex to implement. I've Marked yours as Answer. Thanks!